# typeScript расширение типов

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

пытаюсь написать рекурсивную API  столкнулся с проблемой определения типов

```
const createInstanceHere = function (url: string): AxiosInstance {
  const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: url, headers: {} });
  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
      if (response.data?.error !== undefined) {
        const textError: string = response.data.error;
        notification.error(`При запросе произошла ошибка:${textError}`);
      }
      return response;
    },
    error => {
      notification.error(error.toString());
    }
  );
  return axiosInstance;
};


const api: AxiosInstanceRecursive = {
  createChildInstance: function (nameSpace: string) {
    let baseUrl: string;
    if (this.defaults === undefined) {
      baseUrl = 'url/';
    } else {
      baseUrl = this.defaults.baseURL === undefined ? 'uel/' : this.defaults.baseURL;
    }
    const newInstanceBaseUrl = nameSpace === '/' ? baseUrl : `${baseUrl}${nameSpace}`;
    const newCurrentInstance = createInstanceHere(newInstanceBaseUrl);
    return { ...newCurrentInstance, createChildInstance: this.createChildInstance, parent: this };
  }
};
```

сам тип

```
export interface AxiosInstanceRecursive extends AxiosInstance {
  (key?: keyof AxiosInstance): AxiosInstance;
  parent?: AxiosInstanceRecursive;
  createChildInstance: (param: string) => AxiosInstanceRecursive;
}
```

соотвественно получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос как правильно это сделать или что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если честно, то не очень понял что вы пытаетесь сделать. Поподробнее пожалуйста опишите что вы хотите сделать, чтобы пользователи не гадали

Comment: сори, сам разобрался, так что отпала необходимость

Answer (score 0):

Решилось следующщим образов :
завел 2 разных типа

```
/** @format */
import { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

export interface AxiosInstanceRecursive extends AxiosInstance {
  (key?: keyof AxiosInstance): AxiosInstance[keyof AxiosInstance];
  parent: AxiosInstanceRecursive & AxiosInstance;
  createChildInstance: (param: string) => AxiosInstanceRecursive & AxiosInstance;
}

export interface AxiosObject {
  defaults?: any;
  createChildInstance: (param: string) => AxiosInstanceRecursive & AxiosInstance;
}
```

в коде

```
const api: AxiosObject = {
  createChildInstance: function (nameSpace: string): AxiosInstanceRecursive {
    let baseUrl: string;
    if (this.defaults === undefined) {
      baseUrl = '/';
    } else {
      baseUrl = this.defaults.baseURL === undefined ? '/' : this.defaults.baseURL;
    }
    const newInstanceBaseUrl = nameSpace === '/' ? baseUrl : `${baseUrl}${nameSpace}`;
    const newCurrentInstance = createInstanceHere(newInstanceBaseUrl);
    return <AxiosInstanceRecursive>{ ...newCurrentInstance, createChildInstance: this.createChildInstance, parent: this };
  }
};
```